# Spring contract for HATEOAS service

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-hateoas, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to provide contract for HATEOAS service using spring-cloud-contract solution. However I've stucked with links to HATEOAS resources, as you can run stub server on any random port the question is how to include absolute link returned by contract response and then used by consumer??

Is there any way to inject current stub server port into mapping?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and bumped into your question, can you give me an example of what you mean relative URI links for contract tests? I mean how did you structure your groovy file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to use contract with HATEOAS would be to use the Spring RestDocs solution (you can check out the `restdocs` branch of Oliver's RestBucks sample https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks#documentation--client-stub-generation). We're still working on figuring out the best user experience so any feedback is more than welcome.

As for `Is there any way to inject current stub server port into mapping?`, well, there's nothing really that comes to my mind. I guess you'd have to hardcode the port.

Comment: Finally I switched to relative URI links for contract tests as I couldn't figure out anything better. Anyway thanks for you help.